# Why can't this matrix be diagonalized by its own eigenvector matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have this matrix A diagonalized to the following eigen vectors:
[image]

But forming the following matrix B:

[image]

And then finding its inverse $B^{-1}$:

[image]

I'm unable to diagonalize A with $BAB^{-1}%$:

[image]

Why is this the case? This is just so baffling when it's supposed to work..

Comment: You applied the matrices in the wrong order: the diagonal matrix is $B^{-1}AB$

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out...silly me!

Comment: I've got 1 more question: can I randomly select some x variable to find the eigenvector without doing row reduction? The thing is I won't know if my row reduction can lead to an infinite solution, so is this still allowed? And it's so strange that my eigen vectors when dot product together doesn't give a 0!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From $$AB=BD$$  we get $$B^{-1}AB =D$$

You have it the other way around.

Check the new $$B^{-1}AB =D$$ see if it works out.

Answer (score 0):

The matrix 
$$
M=\begin{pmatrix}
2&-2\\
1&4
\end{pmatrix}
$$
is diagonalizable as
$$
M=BDB^{-1}
$$
where $D$ is the diagonal matrix of the eigenvalues
$$
D=\begin{pmatrix}
3-i & 0\\
0 & 3+i
\end{pmatrix}
$$
and $B$ is the matrix that has as columns the corresponding eigenvectors
$$
B=\begin{pmatrix}
-1-i & -1+i\\
1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$

so we have also
$$
B^{-1}MB=B^{-1}(BDB^{-1})B=D
$$